# Tizen Studio Package Manager: installations failing

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

yesterday I installed `Tizen Studio` and I couldn't get it's `Package Manager` to work...
I was trying to install the `Certificate Manager`.
 The installations started just fine, but after some time it just fails all the installations.

[image]

Here are detailed error messages:
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]
[image: Error 3]
Does anyone know what may be the problem?
Can I somehow manually install the `Certificate Manager`?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you let us know more detailed information regarding your installation environment - os, version, ...?

Comment: You can find error description when clicking failed item. let us know the content of "Inside Trouble Shooting" Popup.

Comment: I'm on a Windows 10 64bit laptop, using Intel chips, I have JDK8 (8u261) and I'm running Tizen Studio 3.7. I will now try downloading again and once it fails I'll tell you the error message. Thanks.

Comment: It's giving me multiple erros. 1. Cannot find the SDK shortcut in Start Menu or Launch-Pad. 2. The Package Manager has unexpectedly quit. 3. Cannot initialize Package Manager. I added the error images in the post if you want to look at them.